# Concatenate mixed types for println

Tags: ios, xcode, concatenation, swift, println

I am trying to concatenate a string and an integer, and log to the console using `println`.

```
println("Load number: " + webViewLoads)
```

webViewLoads is type 'Int'. As I'm mixing two types here, there is no surprise that I'm getting an error:
`Could not find an overload for 'println' that accepts the supplied arguments.`

So, I tried casting webViewLoads `as` a string:
    println("Load: " + webViewLoads as String)

Grr.. Error still thrown.

How can I make this simple little concatenation work?

Comment: use `String(webViewLoads)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180346/append-string-in-swift)

Comment: Also `println("Load: " + (webViewLoads as String))` should work

Comment: @Eduardo, it should not, and won't.

Comment: @holex: you are right

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can create a new String from the Int and concatenate it, or you can use string interpolation.

```
println("Load number: " + String(webViewLoads))
println("Load number: \(webViewLoads)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

```
let string1 = "This is"
let intValue = 45
var appendString = "\(string1) \(intValue)"
println("APPEND STRING:\(appendString)")
```

Comment: He is asking how to append an Int to a String. You are showing two Strings. For the same reason, it is not a duplicate of the other question you mention in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this was mentioned, but this worked for me:

```
println("Frame Width: " + String(stringInterpolationSegment: frameWidth))
```

(frameWidth is: var frameWidth = self.frame.width)